# wxPython: How can I display time into my wxFrame?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to make a program that displays stock information and displays the total loss or gain and the date and time. It is for a python assignment and I have been working on this part alone for a while and can not figure it out. This is the code I have.

```
import wx
import sqlite3
import requests 
import datetime

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="Dialog")

        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label='Read Data', pos=(120, 10))
        
        self.com = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', pos=(30, 40))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Company', pos=(150, 40))

        self.sym = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', (30, 80))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Symbol', (150, 80))

        self.pur = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', (30, 120))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Purchase Price', (150, 120))

        self.cur = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', (30, 160))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Current Price', (150, 160))

        self.sha = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', pos=(200, 40))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Shares', pos=(320, 40))

        self.gl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', pos=(200, 80))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Gain/Loss', pos=(330, 80))

        okBtn = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_OK, pos=(135, 200))

class DataList(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 560))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.lbl0 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Name", pos=(20, 24))

         
        self.table_name = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, pos=(60, 5))
        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT, pos=(20, 30), size=(550, 420))
        # set up columns
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Company', width=100)
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Symbol', width=90)
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'Purchase Price', width=90)
        self.list.InsertColumn(3, 'Current Price', width=90)
        self.list.InsertColumn(4, 'Shares', width=90)
        self.list.InsertColumn(5, 'Gain/Loss', width=90)

                           
        # set up buttons
        display = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Display', size=(-1, 30), pos=(80, 470))
        cancel = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Cancel', size=(-1, 30), pos=(400, 470))

        display.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDisplay)
        cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel)

    def OnDisplay(self, event):
        try:
            self.getAllData()

        except lite.Error as error:
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, str(error), 'Error occured')
            dlg.ShowModal()
            

    def OnCancel(self, event):
        self.Close() # exit program
        


app = wx.App()
dl = DataList(None, -1, 'Read Data')
dl.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This is the code that was given to me to use.

x = datetime.datetime.now() # date and time
date = x.strftime("%A %B %d, %Y : %H:%M")

Comment: Please be more specific - what doesn't work - what statement?

Comment: To get the screen to display - you need ot recognise that you have not define 'panel' in DataList; it's self.panel! If you're learning Python, revise how to access members within a class

Comment: This is the datetime code that was given to me to use. x = datetime.datetime.now()
date = x.strftime("%A %B %d, %Y : %H:%M")

Comment: Do not use this forum for homework assignments - ask your teacher

Comment: Given that you have the required code for the date, (don't use `date` as the variable name, use another name unlikely to be used by another module) once you have the variable defined, use it in a `StaticText` as with you other text values i.e. `wx.StaticText(panel, -1, dt, pos=(180, 475))`. That will get you started, after you've fixed your other errors.